# Google Apps Editor Add-on: Can't create test deployment

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-slides

I have developed a Google Slides Add-on as an editor add-on. I am attempting to get the add-on into a few hands (family/friends) for testing.

- ✅ I can execute the project successfully within Google Slides
- ✅ I have created a Google Cloud Platform project and associated the apps script project with it
- ✅ I have added my handful of users as test users within the GCP project.

I am following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-editor-addons#create_a_test_deployment) to create a test deployment.

- I open the Slides file that contains my add-on script
- I go to the project settings
- I click the blue `Deploy` button and then click `Test deployments`
- I choose the drop-down to select a deployment type

The instructions here say that I should select `Editor Add-on` as the type. However, it is not available. `Google Workspace Add-on` is available, but when selecting it I see the message `To test deployment as Add-on, update the manifest file with Add-on details` and I am unable to create a deployment (presumably because the manifest is different for Workspace and Editor add-ons).

My current `appsscript.json` manifest:

```json
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Slides",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "slides"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations"
  ]
}
```

### Question

- What is the correct way to create a Test Deployment for an editor add-on for Google Workspace from Apps Script that lives inside a Google Slides file?

### Things I've Tried so far

- ❌ Modifying my manifest to be a workplace-style manifest using [instructions like this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/workspace-manifests). Upon attempting to save the manifest, I see validation errors indicating it's the wrong kind of manifest.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#april_13_2022 the Editor Add-On Testing was released 2 days ago (April 13, 2022). Usually the new features take a while to be available for everyone.

According to https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2022/04/apps-script-integrated-development-enviornment-improvements.html

> **Rollout pace**
> Rapid Release and Scheduled Release domains: Gradual rollout (up to 15 days for feature visibility) starting on April 13, 2022

Please be patient.

In the meantime you might try to use the legacy editor to create a test URL.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you! I am a brand new to this ecosystem and hadn't seen any indicators that this was new. I'll attempt to follow the legacy process. I assumed that legacy must have been long ago, not a matter of days 